# PlayBack of simple Katalon scenario failed

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

I recorded a simple scenario with Katalon. When I want to playback the scenario it failed on not finding a recorded webelement altough this element is obvious present in the html of the page. To be sure it is not a timing issue I added a delay of 40 seconds before the failing step. There are no Iframes present in this page.

[image]

Comment: Is there an iframe involved at all?

Comment: No, no Iframe involved at all, just a simple page developed with Vue Js

Comment: @DMart I have found the solution, in the scenario there was a switch to a window with certain title. I had to add manual a switch back to the page. Katalon didn't recorded this switch back itselfs

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario there was a 'switch to window title' added but there was no switch back recorded by Katalon so the webdriver was still pointing to this window instead of the page the scenario had navigated to. I had to add the 'switch to window url' manualy.